# SQL conditional 'WHERE' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to do a conditional `AND` within a SQL `WHERE` clause.
A pseudo code example is below.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [Table]
WHERE
    [A] = [B]
AND
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM [Table2]
        WHERE
            1 = 1
    )
        BEGIN
            --Do conditional filter
            (Table3.[C] = Table.[A])
        END
```

So, if the if condition is true, the rest of the filtering should be applied.
Any help please?

Comment: Look into the CASE syntax - it provides you with conditional ability in a query

Comment: What's the actual condition where you wrote `1 = 1`? That `EXISTS` is totally unrelated to the main query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cater for the chance of the conditional filter and without

```
AND
(
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM [Table2]
        WHERE
            1 = 1
    )
    OR
    (
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM [Table2]
            WHERE
                1 = 1
        )
        AND
        (
            --Do conditional filter
            (Table3.[C] = Table.[A])
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you really need to replicate the exists clause in the `OR` branch? I thought `OR` is short circuit evaluated, so the `OR` branch is only executed if `EXISTS (SELECT ...)`?

Comment: If we only add the Exists with our conditional statement then we are saying for this row to be returned the query needs to exists, if it is evaluated to false the row will not be returned. The not exists is there for rows that will not apply the conditional filters, in this snippet though the select query is not row dependent as it only selects from table2. but if now table 2 does not have any rows the entire select will come up with no results, that is why i just added the not exists, so only once there is a row in table2 will the conditional filters be applied.

Comment: Of course you need to `NOT EXISTS`. My question was whether you really need to check `EXISTS` in the `OR` clause *again* even though the fact that the `OR` clause is executed at all already indicates there *is* a row in `Table2`.

Comment: Oh i see now what you meant. The conditional filter in the OR alone would suffice since Not Exists was false it would mean that exists will be true anyway. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

how about using a `left join`, and checking for `null`? something like this (also pseudo :))

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [Table]
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.id = Table.id
WHERE
    [A] = [B]
AND
    Table2.x IS NULL OR Table3.c = Table.A
```

Comment: In his example, `Table2` doesn't appear to be joinable with `Table`. `Table3` is still a mistery. :)

Answer (score 0):

In a WHERE clause there is not only AND. You can also use OR, NOT and parentheses. Thus you can express any combination of conditions. In your example you don't want to select any data when there is a table2 entry but no matching table3 entry.

```
select *
from table1 t1
where a = b
and not
(
   exists (select * from table2)
   and
   not exists (select * from table3 t3 where t3.c = t1.a)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I think this is a best way to achieve what you need:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [Table]
WHERE
    [A] = [B]
AND
(
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM [Table2]
        WHERE 1 = 1
    )
    OR
        --Do conditional filter
        (Table3.[C] = Table.[A])
)
```

Note that I used a `NOT EXISTS` and an `OR`conditional. This way, if no rows in `Table2` satisfy the `WHERE`, the `NOT EXISTS` is `true` and the second condition doesn't matter. Otherwise, the `OR` will be true depending on the last condition.

I am assuming `Table3` is joined to `Table` in that query, right? Because otherwise of course you couldn't do that last condition. It would be great if you could post a query closer to the one you are actually using.

PS: I guess the `1 = 1` is not the real condition, right? As I asked you in a comment, are both this condition as well as `[A] = [B]` totally unrelated to the other tables?

Answer (score -1):

```
This will help you : 

DECLARE @SelectQuery    VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @WhereCondition VARCHAR(50) = ''

SET @SelectQuery = 'SELECT *
                    FROM [Table]
                    WHERE [A] = [B]'

IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM [Table2]
            WHERE 1 = 1
        )
BEGIN
    --Do conditional filter
    SET @WhereCondition = ' AND (Table3.[C] = Table.[A])'
END

EXEC (@SelectQuery + @WhereCondition)
```

Comment: OUCH! Don't use `exec` unless really required!

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar : May I know why? Please tell me or refer me a link that talks about it. Thanks!! :)

Comment: First of all, this is typical for programmers that don't have database background. They abuse SQL to work as they'd program in their favourite procedural language. This is just not how SQL works. Secondly, using `exec` within a stored procedure to execute dynamic SQL does not play well with parameters to the stored procedure/local variables, etc. Thirdly it leaves the doors wide open for SQL injections and the like. Last but not least: Your code is much harder to understand than for example Hano's.

Comment: Okay!! Got it!! Thanks for the quality time you spent for the explanation. I will try not to use EXEC in stored procedure henceforth. :-)